# Toggle menu only when it is open when we click anywhere on window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on one scenario in that I have menu which toggle on one button.
When I click on that Menu button it opens fine.

**Problem persist with this code:**

When I click on anywhere it toggle with open and close.

**Now What I need is**

When I click on anywhere on window menu should close but only when it is in open state. toggle only when it is in open state.

**HTML Code :**

```
<section id="wrapper"> <!-- Sidebar -->
    <aside id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <div class="togglebtn"><a href="#menu-toggle" id="menu-toggle"></a></div>
          <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li class="sidebar-brand"> <a href="#" class="ripple">
              <div class="icon"><i class="demo-icon icon-meeter"></i></div>
              <div class="nav-label"> <span>Dashboard</span></div>
              </a> 
             </li>
          </ul>
    </div>
</aside> 
</section>
```

**JavaScript code:**

```
<script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });

    $("body").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
</script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: where is wrapper div in your html???

Comment: @Jayababu- HTML code updated. thanks for point out this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your `$("body").click` function:

```
$("body").click(function () {
    $("#wrapper").removeClass("toggled");
});
```

Right now what's happening is that you are "toggling" the class every time any part of the body is clicked. *Toggling* turns a class on **or** off depending on its current state. You need to just ensure that it is removed when the body is clicked.

You can actually use `toggleClass` to accomplish this, but you must tell it you are wanting to remove the class by passing it a `state` parameter.

```
$("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled", false);
```

See the jQuery documentation for toggleClass: http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/